# dot product of vectors with not orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, products

The dot produt (inner product in the context of Euclidean space) of two vectors $\mathbf{a}=\left [ a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n} \right]$ and $\mathbf{b}=\left [ b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{n} \right ]$ is defined as:

$\left ( \textrm{0.1}\right )$ $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}$

in Wikipedia that quotes S. Lipschutz, M. Lipson (2009). Linear Algebra. McGraw Hill.

Given that  the basis of the subspace is $\left \{ \mathbf{e}_{1}, \mathbf{e}_{2}, ... , \mathbf{e}_{n},\right \}$ then $\mathbf{a}=a_{1}\mathbf{e}_{1}+a_{2}\mathbf{e}_{2}+ ... + a_{n}\mathbf{e}_{n}$ and $\mathbf{b}=b_{1}\mathbf{e}_{1}+b_{2}\mathbf{e}_{2}+ ... + b_{n}\mathbf{e}_{n}$, then:

$\left ( \textrm{0.2}\right )$ $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}= a_{1}b_{1}\mathbf{e}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{1}+a_{1}b_{2}\mathbf{e}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{2}+... +a_{1}b_{n}\mathbf{e}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{n} + ... + a_{n}b_{n}\mathbf{e}_{n}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{n}$

so:

- if the basis is composed of pairwise orthogonal vectors then  $\mathbf{e}_{i}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{i}=1$ and $\mathbf{e}_{i}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{j}=0$ with $i\neq j$ then $\left ( \textrm{0.2}\right )$ is reduced to $\left ( \textrm{0.1}\right )$
- if the basis is composed of not pairwise orthogonal vectors, then $\left ( \textrm{0.2}\right )$ can be written as:

$\left ( \textrm{0.3}\right )$ 
$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{j}b_{i}\mathbf{e_{j}}\cdot \mathbf{e_{i}}$

and actually $\left ( \textrm{0.3}\right )$ is not equivalent to the general definition $\left ( \textrm{0.1}\right )$.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are confused by...

Comment: @Illegal Immigrantn the case with not orthogonal basis $\mathbf{e}_{i}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{j}\neq0$ with $i\neq j$ so the value of the dot product cannot be computed with $\left ( \textrm{0.1}\right )$.

Comment: I notice that you put a bibliographic citation for eq. (0.1). Since you initially posted your question, have you found a bibliographic citation for eq. (0.3)? If anyone has such reference, please provide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't missing anything, (0.1) is the expression of the dot product with respect to an orthonormal basis. If the basis is not orthonormal you get (0.3). Notice that you do not just need the vectors to be pairwise orthogonal, but also of unit norm in order for (0.1) to hold.

Comment: I was thinking so as well but the fact that this conditions aren't specified made me doubt (I cited Wikipedia but I noticed the same in many texts).

Answer (score 1):

You're Got it. But 0.1 is not the general definition. It is the definition of dot product for vectors of same basis. 0.3 is more general as it shows you must dot the basis (plural) together. 0.3 reduces to 0.1 when they have the same basis thus the dot product of the basis (plural) is 1.